# Passing a variable into a START clause via the WITH result from a previous query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph structure with "hyperedges" - edge properties with a unique property of some node in the graph. I'd like to write a Cypher query that finds such edges and then uses the value of that property with a subsequent `START` clause to find the referenced node. I've tried a few things but the closest I've come is this:

```
MATCH (start)-[relationship]->(end)
WHERE HAS(relationship.source)
WITH start, end, relationship.source AS source
START src = node:node_auto_index(src = {source})
RETURN start, end, src
```

which complains with `Expected a parameter named source`.

Dropping the brackets from `{source}` also produces an error:

```
START src = node:node_auto_index(src = source)
```

I can pass the value through to a `WHERE` clause in the subsequent query like this:

```
MATCH (start)-[relationship]->(end)
WHERE HAS(relationship.source)
WITH start, end, relationship.source AS source
MATCH (src)
WHERE src.src = source
RETURN start, end, src
```

but this doesn't take advantage of the legacy index causing the query to be very slow.

Is there a way to pass the result from a prior query to a `START` clause through `WITH`?

Comment: +1 for a good question!  I wish I had the answer, but I'm hoping the eventual answer is, "This shouldn't matter, because we're going to make `MATCH` be able to exploit legacy indexes in a future release, so you just wouldn't use `START` in the first place."   I know this doesn't help you today though.